# Explain to a layperson why text-to-speech (TTS) has made little progress?

Tags: machine-learning

I am a layperson who has searched for years in vain for a human-sounding TTS program, but it seems that over the years, hardly any progress has been made (a purely unscientific evaluation using just my ear and also the ears of many others). It still sounds like the same robotic word-by-word reading-out that I believe was already accomplished decades ago.

This is puzzling (for a layperson like me who doesn't know anything about data science, linguistics, machine learning, etc.). Especially when contrasted to say speech-to-text or driverless cars, which have noticeably improved over the years.

Could you explain to a layperson (like myself) why, in early 2017, do most text-to-speech (TTS) programs still sound so robotic and non-human-like? And why so little progress has been made (especially in comparison to some other achievements)?

Might it just be that there simply isn't much demand for TTS (as compared to speech-to-text or driverless cars) and so few resources have been devoted to this?

(If this isn't the right StackExchange for the question, I apologize in advance. Please migrate this to a more suitable StackExchange site instead, thanks!)

Comment: I don't agree that today's mass-market text-to-speech as found in Siri, satnavs, and so on, is no better than that of 'decades ago'. Do you actually feel that is so or are you saying that improvements have only been achieved by greater available storage and processing power, and not by better underlying algorithms? There's clearly a demand for TTS but perhaps less demand for incremental improvements to the quality of speech output - maybe it's now good enough for most purposes?

Comment: @nekomatic: People don't seem to mind a sentence or two from Siri, satnavs, etc ("You have an appointment at 3pm today." "Turn left in 300 meters.") But many people get incredibly annoyed when you use these for longer passages (a few minutes long or a book). I personally do not get too annoyed (though I can obviously tell it's robotic), but when I try to use TTS for recordings stretching only a few minutes, many of my listeners protest strongly.

Answer (score 6):

Text-to-speech suffers from problems similar to the drivers of "[uncanny valley](http://www.tsdconference.org/tsd2014/download/preprints/673.pdf)" effects when viewing faces of humanoid robots and computer renderings of faces. Our ability to distinguish depth of meaning, emotional content and other subtle cues makes humans very sensitive to small details in audio containing spoken language. Note this is not quite the same as claiming text-to-speech actually *has* an "uncanny valley"; there doesn't appear to be much analysis of that claim either way around.

Existing text-to-speech systems have two basic generative processes: *Concatenative* models are essentially databases of phoneme samples that the system strings together. These suffer from lack of flexibility. *Parametric* models attempt to represent sound generation at a lower level to improve on this, but it is quite a challenge to create a model that includes all the fine detail that we notice. For instance, we notice many non-verbal cues including imperfections such as mouth noise, breathing etc.

There has been recent progress in this area by researchers running a very detailed generative model - one that literally generates sound, sample by sample, after consuming a large amount of training data.

[This report on WaveNet by DeepMind team](https://deepmind.com/blog/wavenet-generative-model-raw-audio/) explains the different synthesis techniques used to date and shows off the capabilities of the new approach.

The process creates state-of-the-art results, and it is easy to hear the improvement from examples on the site. However, it is too computationally intensive to be used in real-time systems yet. Give it a few years to be refined, and it could be the basis of far better text-to-speech systems.

---

The above written in January 2017. In the intervening time (it is now October 2017) the DeepMind team have been working on the efficiency of their model, and [it is now much faster and sounds even better](https://deepmind.com/blog/wavenet-launches-google-assistant/). This is close to becoming a solved problem, albeit with some proprietary ownership. Give it a little while longer though and this breakthrough will allow real-time and natural-sounding parametric voice models in many applications.

Comment: When you reference the 'uncanny valley', do you mean to say that there is a point at which improvements to computer speech actually become disturbing, or less satisfying, to the listener? I could believe that callers to an automated phone system might be less annoyed if the computer had a recognisable computer voice rather than an odd-sounding human one, but it would be nice to have some evidence.

Comment: @nekomatic: I linked "uncanny valley" to one piece of research on the topic, just to demonstrate its a thing. It is not as clearly researched as with animation/3D/robotics, and seems to get conflated with animation issues, as lip animation/sync with audio is a strong driver for uncanny valley in video. The research I linked is equivocal about it being an effect, but the fact there is research at all, using the same terminology, I think shows it is impacting development.

Comment: Very interesting addition thanks (although I'm not sure if the statistics are correctly used given the multiple comparisons).

Comment: I don't know though if people are annoyed because of some uncanny valley effect. It seems more like people are annoyed because it's still very obviously robotic and nowhere near human-like. (This is in contrast to humanoid robots.)

Comment: @KennyLJ: Yes, my reference to "uncanny valley" is more to do with human sensitivity to detail. I'm trying to say that in audio for voices we are just as sensitive as for faces. Even with perfect top-level accuracy, we notice stuff - e.g. for faces, you can have super-accurate shape and skin tone in a model, but we notice and expect micro-movements, minor imperfections etc. It is similar for audio. I don't have any references or data explicitly demonstrating "uncanny valley" triggering specific reactions in audio, although I do think it exists. I may try to clarify that later in the answer.